# How to grab Android Device Screen in Real-time (40-60 FPS) for frame processing (ROOTED DEVICE) (Exclude/Ignore Overlay View)

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, screenshot

I currently use MediaProjection to grab the screen frame (I do not want Camera Stream, I want the device stream), process it with openCV and then draw some lines on an overlay (Hough Lines), then add this overlay on screen.

Since MediaProjection records whatever is present on the screen, it includes my openCV Overlay in the subsequent screenshots which is not desired.

I need a way to take screenshots while ignoring this overlay view, and this needs to be done as close to real-time as possible.

My goal is to process the screen data (frame by frame) of OTHER Apps(Preferably anything showing on the screen), not my own app.

Since I use a rooted device, I am open to all suggestions like using custom ROMS/OS or any other technical wizardry.

I am using a ROOTED Device and will run my app on the same device.
I have tried to use:
1) MediaProjection API
2) System/bin/ScreenCap

I have also tried to "HIDE" my overlay view just before taking the screenshot, but it doesn't seem to work since the MediaProjection or ScreenCap images are not actually real-time but a few seconds old.

I have used this app as my starting point:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaProjection/andshooter

All code is the same except some additional OpenCV operations.

These are some samples from the code that I am running:
[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOJpr.png)
[After Processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6aH5.png)

I want to exclude the processing/lines the next time I fetch my screenshot.
Is there any way to do this?